# Displaying of larger initial Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing the first larger Image as the page loads,
But I want to show the larger Images as I click on thumbnail image, initially I dont want to show any larger image as I load the page. only thumbnails should be shown initially.

This is the tried link:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/38/

```
$("#panel img").hide(); //<= remove the :not(first-child) filter

$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow").click(function(){
    getIndex = $(this).index();
    $("#thumbs .clicked").removeClass('clicked');
    $("#panel img").fadeOut('fast').eq(getIndex).fadeIn();  
    $(this).addClass('clicked');     
});

//$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow:first").click(); //<= don't simulate the first click
$(['next','prev']).each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $('.'+that).click(function(){
        $('#thumbs .clicked')[that]().click();
    });
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment this line -

```
//$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow:first").click();
```

And add `$('#panel img').hide();` in the beginning

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/39/)

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to each thumbnail div:

```
rel="http://images1.videolan.org/images/largeVLC.png"
```

to get:

```
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem UiUx3DSSVSelected" id="__item0-__set0-0" data--ui="__item0-__set0-0" rel="http://images1.videolan.org/images/largeVLC.png">
```

Then use code like the following to lazy load the images:

```
$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow").click(function(){
    getIndex = $(this).index();
    $("#thumbs .clicked").removeClass('clicked');
    $("#panel img").attr("src",$(this).attr("rel")); 
    $(this).addClass('clicked');     
});
```

It is demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/L7yKp/55/

You can hide the following line to display nothing, initially:

```
//$(".displayimage").attr("src",$($("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow")[0]).attr("rel"));
```

hth